# JULIA ODBC.query MethodError: no method matching eachcolumn

Tags: ms-access, odbc, julia

I've been using Julia for some graphical results, using ODBC to conect MS Access database to get the data.
The same function worked flawlesly two weeks ago, but now it throws an error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching eachcolumn(::Tables.CopiedColumns{NamedTuple{(:year, :Fact),Tuple{Array{Union{Missing, Int16},1},Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}}}})

Closest candidates are:
  eachcolumn(::Union{Function, Type}, ::Tables.Schema{names,nothing}, ::Any) where names at C:\Users\myuser\.julia\packages\Tables\TA7NF\src\utils.jl:109
  eachcolumn(::Union{Function, Type}, ::Tables.Schema{names,types}, ::Any) where {names, types} at C:\Users\myuser\.julia\packages\Tables\TA7NF\src\utils.jl:66

Stacktrace:

 [1] #fromcolumns#410(::Bool, ::typeof(DataFrames.fromcolumns), ::Tables.CopiedColumns{NamedTuple{(:anno, :Fact),Tuple{Array{Union{Missing, Int16},1},Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}}}}) at C:\Users\myuser\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\other\tables.jl:13

 [2] (::DataFrames.var"#kw##fromcolumns")(::NamedTuple{(:copycols,),Tuple{Bool}}, ::typeof(DataFrames.fromcolumns), ::Tables.CopiedColumns{NamedTuple{(:anno, :Fact),Tuple{Array{Union{Missing, Int16},1},Array{Union{Missing, 
Float64},1}}}}) at .\none:0

 [3] #DataFrame#412(::Bool, ::Type{DataFrame}, ::ODBC.Query{missing,NamedTuple{(:anno, :Fact),Tuple{Union{Missing, Int16},Union{Missing, Float64}}},Tuple{Array{Union{Missing, Int16},1},Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}}}) at C:\Users\myuser\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\other\tables.jl:32

 [4] DataFrame(::ODBC.Query{missing,NamedTuple{(:anno, :Fact),Tuple{Union{Missing, Int16},Union{Missing, Float64}}},Tuple{Array{Union{Missing, Int16},1},Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}}}) at C:\Users\myuser\.julia\packages\DataFrames\yH0f6\src\other\tables.jl:23

 [5] #query#15(::Bool, ::Bool, ::Dict{Int64,Function}, ::typeof(ODBC.query), ::ODBC.DSN, ::String, ::Type{DataFrame}) at C:\Users\myuser\.julia\packages\ODBC\YEzHX\src\Query.jl:390

 [6] query(::ODBC.DSN, ::String, ::Type{DataFrame}) at C:\Users\myuser\.julia\packages\ODBC\YEzHX\src\Query.jl:385

 [7] query(::ODBC.DSN, ::String) at C:\Users\myuser\.julia\packages\ODBC\YEzHX\src\Query.jl:376

 [8] top-level scope at C:\Users\myuser\Documents\Fact.jl:94
```

Seems like there is some kind of incompatibility between Query.jl and tables.jl

Here is the code used:

```
 using DataFrames
 using DataStreams
 using ODBC
 using StatsBase
 using Plots

 myDNS = ODBC.DSN("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=C:/Users/myuser/Documents/Data.accdb")

 strFactQuery = "SELECT YEAR(FFact) AS anno, SUM(Invoiced) AS Fact FROM Invoices GROUP BY YEAR(FFact)"
 FactResults = ODBC.query(myDNS, strFactQuery)
```

Is there anyone with the same problem? maybe it's a Query.jl bug?

Regards

Comment: what versions of ODBC.jl, Tables.jl and DataFrames.jl are you on? It seems that ODBC.jl is not up to date with the latest release of Tables.jl but to be sure what is going on can you please share the versions?

Comment: ODBC v0.8.5
DataFrames v0.19.4

Comment: forgot   Tables v1.0.1

Comment: After doing a "test DataFrame", some issues showed up

`Test Summary:  | Pass  Fail  Error  Total
Tables         |   18     1      6     25
  basics       |    9                   9
  Row-style    |    6            1      7
  Column-style |    2            1      3
  Extras       |    1     1      4      6
        FAILED: tables.jl`

Comment: you should downgrade Tables.jl to 0.2.11 as your set of packages is not compatible. Tables. 1.0.1 introduced breaking changes to the API that are not incorporated in your versions of ODBC.jl and DataFrames.jl (the problem is caused by ODBC.jl version).

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to Tables v 0.2.11 solved the problem, but beeing able to get that version was a PITA as downgrading via pkg mannager was not possible because some dependency problems, so, all in all, I went to github, selected the version, copied the code and pasted over the library code in my environment...maybe not the ellegant way, but worked.